Wrong character suspected in 贪楼地窥视
Users suspect 楼 is a wrong character in 窜到泰安火车站，溜进候车室里，贪楼地窥视着过往行人、旅客、小商小贩…… suggesting possible replacement 欲, cf. 自以为是竟投案自首，1986年泰安“10·18”杀人劫车案侦破始末. https://www.163.com/dy/article/J05CIC1U0543A3A8.html

The pinyin of 楼 is lóu, and the true character is 婪(lán). The typist may input wrong character by clicking key L.
The whole words is 贪婪 which means someone is greedy.
